# Invalid link in Duplicate Detection Job email in Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2013

Tags: dynamics-crm

We are using Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2013, Currently the email we are getting after running duplicate detection job contains link which is not working. If we copy the link into address bar it works, but tried to open the link by clicking on it then gives an error message.

Comment: The error message you're getting?

Answer (score 2):

Please check Email Templates with Advanced Find for the "Duplicate Detection Task Completion Template" System Job template. It has the URL hardcoded in.